# AngularJS: Update DOM after hidden panel is shown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the AngularJS range slider directive from [prajwalkman](http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/). The slider works fine while it is visible, but when it is embedded in a hidden options screen using ng-show, the DOM manipulation bits dont work due to the use of "offsetWidth". I am using these sliders in a panel that is by default hidden at screen launch, but still want to initialize the sliders so the pointers are at the correct positions and the colored selection bar is visible when the user toggles the panel.

```
wholeBar = element.children()[0].offsetWidth;
```

When the element is hidden offsetWidth is 0 and the calculations dont work correctly. I think what I need to do is show the panel, then run the DOM update code but I havent been able to figure out how to schedule it to run after the current apply/digest cycle completes.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcL500wm/4/) that is vastly simplified to show what I mean - when the DIV is shown the code works because offsetWidth is not 0, but when it is hidden the selection bar doesn't expand to 50%.

Comment: you can use `transform: translate(-2000px, 0)` or similar to give it layout off screen instead of `ng-hide` / `ng-show` - make a custom `ng-class="{}"`  etc.

Comment: Ideally your bar width should be driven from a model (a scope value) rather than having a listener telling it to increase. This would be a better design (and would not suffer from this problem.)

Comment: https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider -> this fork has a workaround.

Comment: The example I used in the fiddle is a little contrived, the pointer's position is actually stored in the model (ie 3 of 10) but the calculation is done in the directive since the wholeBar is set to 100%, it has to calculate how many pixels 3/10=30% is. I suppose I could set the selected bar to 30% instead of a px value so I will try that out as well.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar for finding that fork - I have actually heavily modified prajwalkman's as well. I made a similar workaround to venturocket's, but I missed the $timeout part. Using $timeout fixed this issue for me as it allowed the digest/apply cycle to complete before running the updateDOM() function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As comments mentioned, a simple solution would be to use a class to just move the slider out of view, effectively 'hiding' it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcL500wm/10/)

I accomplished this by making the hide/show button toggle a var

```
<button ng-init="move=false" ng-click="move=!move">Show/Hide DIV</button>
```

creating a class to move the element off the screen

```
.move {
  transform: translate(-9999px, 0);
}
```

and using ng-class to apply the class when we toggle the button

```
<div ng-class="{move: move}" my-component>
    <h3>This is my hidden DIV</h3>

    <div style="height:20px; width:100%; background-color:red; zindex=0; ">
        <div style="height:35px; width:15px; background-color:blue; zindex=1; position:absolute"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```